# save multiple data frame in one variable

Tags: python, pandas

I appended several data frames in one variable (Cy_info), and i want to use this variable as a function argument(fnames). This function
I used the following:

```
def buildOrm(fnames, twissfile, plane, dkick):
    for i in range(len(fnames)):
        ore = OrbitResponse()  #####
        orb_file = fnames[i]
        ref_file = twissfile

        x, y =  getBpms(orb_file)
        n_bpms = len(x)
        orm = ORM1(len(fnames), n_bpms)
        ore.orbits['refOrbit'] = getBpms(ref_file)
        i_cor = 0
        for i in fnames:
            print('reading', "Cx_info_"+str(i))
            orb_file=i
            ore.hcors.append(i)
            #cname = fnames[i].replace('orm_'+plane+'_','')
            ipage = 0
            ore.orbits[i] = getBpms(orb_file)
```

I got the error from the last line of the code, when i called the function:

```
names = Cy_info
ormy, ore = buildOrm(names,twiss_error,  plane='y', dkick=1.e-4)

error: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'
```

How can i save multiple data frame in one variable and then deal with them individually?

Comment: "How can i save multiple data frame in one variable and then deal with them individually?" - depends on that variable. If the variable is a list then yes: `list_of_df[0]`, `list_of_df[1]`, ... If you merge several dataframe into one new dataframe you loose the information, which part of that variable comes from which original dataframe

Comment: You have two for loops using `i` - not great. In the outer loop i is an integer, and if `Cy_info` is a dataframe this will throw an error; if `Cy_info` is a list of dataframes this will work. As for the inner loop, if `Cy_info` (and therefore `fnames`) is a dataframe it will iterate over the column names of `fnames`.  Try `ore.orbits.loc[i] = getBpms(orb_file)` or `ore.orbits.loc[:,i] = getBpms(orb_file)`. If `Cy_info`  is a list the statement `ore.orbits[i]` makes no sense, it will only accept integers for i. In this case try `for j, i in enumerate(fnames):` ... and `ore.orbits[j] = `...

Comment: @konstanze I tried to use ore.orbits.loc[i] but i got the error : 'at.physics.orbit' has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: you need to show us your input variable `Cy_info`

Comment: @konstanze Cy_info, is a multiple data frames appended in a list, for example the first line of Cy_info is as the following and it is repeated many time :
[     s_pos  closed_orbitx  closed_orbity     betax      betay  \
 0     1.40       0.000138       0.000061  5.784010   6.093289   
 1     4.31       0.000209       0.000009  3.094373  10.690371   
 2     7.21       0.000306       0.000012  5.791000   6.041045   
 3    10.12       0.000138      -0.000075  3.093292  10.561512   
 4    13.02      -0.000016      -0.000056  5.782973   5.985492